# USB device not listed as tty*

Tags: arch-linux, usb, udev, tty

I'm trying to get a ST-Link v2 programmer listed as a tty*.

On

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Host: Inspiron 7580
Kernel: 5.5.2-arch1-1
```

Plugging the device in gives the following output for

```
journalctl -a

kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=3748, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-1: Product: STM32 STLink
kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: SÿnReIBg
```

For

```
lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x3748 ST-LINK/V2
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
  iProduct                2 STM32 STLink
  iSerial                 3 SÿnReIBg
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              4 ST Link
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

My udev rule for `idVendor=0483, idProduct=3748` is `49-stlinkv2.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3748", \
    MODE:="0666", \
    SYMLINK+="stlinkv2_%n"
```

The device worked on Ubuntu before.

The embedded ST-Link of a Nucleo-64 board is listed as `ttyACM0` without trouble.
Output for the working nucleo board:

```
journalctl -a

kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=374b, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-1: Product: STM32 STLink
kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 066DFF494849887767073715
kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
kernel: scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.1
kernel: cdc_acm 1-1:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MBED     microcontroller  1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 328 512-byte logical blocks: (168 kB/164 KiB)
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk

lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 032: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x374b ST-LINK/V2.1
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
  iProduct                2 STM32 STLink
  iSerial                 3 066DFF494849887767073715
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0080
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              300mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              4 ST-Link Debug
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              5 ST-Link mass storage
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         2
  bInterfaceCount         2
  bFunctionClass          2 Communications
  bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
  bFunctionProtocol       1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
  iFunction               6 ST-Link VCP Ctrl
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
  iInterface              6 ST-Link VCP Ctrl
  CDC Header:
    bcdCDC               1.10
  CDC Call Management:
    bmCapabilities       0x00
    bDataInterface          3
  CDC ACM:
    bmCapabilities       0x06
      sends break
      line coding and serial state
  CDC Union:
    bMasterInterface        2
    bSlaveInterface         3 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
    bInterval             255
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        3
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              7 ST-Link VCP Data
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
    bInterval               0
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

My udev rule for `idVendor=0483, idProduct=374b` is `49-stlinkv2-1.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="374a", \
    MODE:="0666", \
    SYMLINK+="stlinkv2-1_%n"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="374b", \
    MODE:="0666", \
    SYMLINK+="stlinkv2-1_%n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that the working device is reported as:

```
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1
```

while the problem device is reported as:

```
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
```

[Please see this overview of ST-LINK versions on page 2 of this PDF.](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/technical_note/group0/30/c8/1d/0f/15/62/46/ef/DM00290229/files/DM00290229.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00290229.pdf)

The embedded ST-LINK in your Nucleo-64 board is a ST-LINK/V2-1, which has some extra USB interfaces: an USB mass storage interface and a virtual COM port. The latter is what gets listed as a `ttyACMn` device in Linux.

The basic ST-LINK/V2 (without the -1 suffix) does not have a virtual COM port, so there is nothing that could be mapped as a TTY device.

On power-up, the basic ST-LINK/V2 will be in firmware upgrade mode, and requires a dedicated command to switch into STM8 or STM32 debug mode (depending on the loaded firmware). On the other hand, ST-LINK/V2-1 and newer start with the firmware already running, and require a dedicated command to switch into firmware upgrade mode.

The [`stlink-tool` utility](https://github.com/texane/stlink) does not actually use the TTY device, but raw USB commands. It uses `libusb-1.0`, so to use `stlink-tool`, you'll need to make sure that the appropriate raw USB device node at `/dev/bus/usb/*/*` is accessible to your user account. If the `lsusb` command reports the device as `Bus 001 Device 031`, then the correct device node will be `/dev/bus/usb/001/031` respectively.

Comment: Just tested flashing, the command `st-flash write firmware.bin 0x8000000` worked. Thanks.